# Scale desktop 4:3 to 16:9

Tags: windows, windows-7

I need to scale my display, however I cannot seem to find how to do that. The problem is, when I set my resolution to 1280x720, it stretches, as my default resolution is 1280x1024. I would like to scale it so it doesn't stretch, in the same way when watching movies - black bars appear at the top and bottom of the screen. Is there any way to do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Since this question has nothing to do with programming, it really doesn't belong here. The best answer I can give you is that the reaction of your monitor to a change in resolution is completely up to the monitor itself, and your description is how most (all?) of them work. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: Have you checked if your monitor has an option to change that behavior? Many do, under something like "Menu->Display Settings". And yeah, stack overflow is not the place to be asking this question.